# EHOSTUNREACH error while sending HTTP request from Hubot to Rails app locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, coffeescript, hubot

I am developing a Slack bot (using [Hubot](https://hubot.github.com/docs/)) as well as a Rails app that will receive HTTP requests from it and process them accordingly. Basically, the high-level steps of what I want to do are like this:

1. A slack user sends a trigger word to the bot (let's say the trigger is "bye").
2. Hubot picks up the trigger, then sends a request to the Rails app.
3. Rails app marks the Slack user as out of office.

I seem to have some sort of routing issue, because I get the `EHOSTUNREACH` error when I try to execute this flow with both apps booted (`rails s` for Rails and `./bin/hubot --adapter slack` for Hubot). I'm guessing that Hubot is unable to reach the Rails app at all.
Am I missing something here? What URL do I need to use to enable these apps to send requests to each other?

I've also tried swapping out the `127.0.0.1:3000` with `localhost:3000`, but the results stayed the same.

**Hubot code**

```cs
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /bye/i, (res) ->
    res.reply('Later alligator')
    robot.logger.info 'Will proceed to clock out user'

    data = JSON.stringify({
      slack_user_id: res.message.user.id
    })
    robot.http("127.0.0.1:3000/")
      .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .post(data) (err, resp, body) ->
        if err
          robot.logger.info "Encountered an error: #{err}"
        else
          robot.logger.info 'Successfully sent HTTP request to Rails app'
```

**Log results when I send trigger word to bot**

```sh
INFO Will proceed to clock out user
INFO Encountered an error: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.11.184:80 - Local (192.168.91.168:60029)
```

**Rails server log** (it's definitely port 3000)

```
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Check what you get in a browser with http://localhost:3000, if it doesn't work you likely have local network config issues. If it does work, try changing you code to `robot.http("http://localhost:3000")` and update your post with the result. Your error message seems to indicate it is attempting to connect on port 80.

Comment: @DaveSatchell I changed it to `robot.http("http://localhost:3000")` and it worked. Kind of embarrassed that it was such a trivial issue... thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted as an answer so you can accept and close the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the request to `robot.http("http://localhost:3000")` ensuring you have the protocol at the beginning.